# Converting a database table into JSON stream

Tags: c#, json

I have a key-value pair database table and need to convert it to a JSON stream programmaticlally using C#.

My table structure:

```
Table1
__________
Category
Title
Type
StageNumber
LineNumber
Key
Value
```

So I am going to need all of the fields: Category, Title, Type, StageNumber, LineNumber, and then the Key and Value in my stream.

I have created a class:

```
public class MyRecord
{

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int StageNumber { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string FieldKey { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to JSON, so could someone please point me in the right direction on how to proceed?

Comment: Fill your object *MyRecord*, than call *JsonConvert.SerializeObject*, that is all.

Comment: I am new to this so I am going top need more details and some samples

Comment: Google it. SO is full of similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way is:

```
var obj = new MyRecord();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

For what you need a stream?

Comment: How do I fill obj with several instances of class MyRecord?

Comment: var obj = new List<MyRecord>();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);

Comment: List<MyRecord> lst = ....;
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst); <--ERROR HERE 
"The length of a string exceeds the maxJSonLength property". I filled lst from the database with about 53K records.

Comment: @ElenaDBA it's another issue, look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Answer (score -1):

//Serialize
var obj = new MyRecord();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);

//Deserialize
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(obj);